# Proof of Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence on $\Bbb R$ and $a\in \Bbb R$ with $a_{n+1}-a_n\rightarrow a$. Show that $\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow a$

MY Attempt:

First, I layed out how one would usually go about it. Obviously, if $a_{n+1}-a_n\rightarrow a$, then $|a_{n+1}-a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. Then I thought maybe i take the absolute value sign away maybe i'll see something.

$$-\epsilon+a<a_{n+1}-a_n<\epsilon+a$$ or
$$\frac{-\epsilon+a}{n}<\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n}<\frac{\epsilon+a}{n}$$

Couldn't think of anything that would help...

Then i thought maybe another way:

$$\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{a_N}{n}+\sum_{i=N}^{n-1}\frac{a_{N+1}-a_N}{n}$$

Then

$$\frac{a_n}{n}-a=\frac{a_N}{n}+\sum_{i=N}^{n-1}\frac{a_{N+1}-a_N}{n}-a$$

Then im stuck again....I didnt post this because its kind of embarrassing...

Comment: What have you tried? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_%E2%88%99/%E2%88%9E_case), perhaps?

Comment: eh just the usual method, but i dont seem to be able to somehow get $a_n/n \rightarrow a$

Comment: Then you should edit your question to show "the usual method".

Comment: Yeah i did that....I dont know why i got so many downvotes thou many other people do the same and they get upvotes

Comment: Voted to reopen

Comment: @DavidP Me too.

Comment: it is really just a direct application of the theorem that J.G. linked.....

Comment: Supposing you wanted to do it more directly, your sum expression at the end there actually works fine! Put absolute values on both sides, use the triangle inequality, and use your inequality for $\frac{1}{n}(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ for large $n$, and it should work (I’ve not written this out to properly check but it appears that way)

Comment: Thanks, Jerry, for your edit and improved context.  It helps us better understand where, and why, you are stuck, rather than us having to guess. +1

Comment: "I dont know why i got so many downvotes thou many other people do the same and they get upvotes "  No, they don't.  I've never seen anyone not show their work and say the tried things but not say what ever get an upvote.  Who has ever gotten an upvote doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an $\epsilon\gt0$ arbitrary, and since $a_{n+1}-a_n\to a$ for all $n\ge N$ for some $N\in\Bbb N$ you have, as you mentioned:

$$\frac{a-\epsilon}{n}\lt\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n}\lt\frac{a+\epsilon}{n}$$

As you also mentioned, you can use telescoping series to find, for all $n\ge N$:

$$\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{a_N}{n}+\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}\frac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{n}$$

All you had to do to complete the proof (Stolz-Cesaro does it immediately, but this one you can do more elementarily) is to use the above inequality and equality together:

$$\begin{align}\forall n(\in\Bbb N)\gt N:\quad\frac{a_N}{n}+\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}\frac{a-\epsilon}{n}&\lt\frac{a_n}{n}\lt\frac{a_N}{n}+\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}\frac{a+\epsilon}{n}\\\frac{a_N}{n}+\frac{1}{n}(n-N)(a-\epsilon)&\lt\frac{a_n}{n}\lt\frac{a_N}{n}+\frac{1}{n}(n-N)(a+\epsilon)\\\frac{1}{n}(a_N-N(a-\epsilon))+a-\epsilon&\lt\frac{a_n}{n}\lt a+\epsilon+\frac{1}{n}(a_N-N(a+\epsilon))\end{align}$$

The quantity $(a_N-N(a\pm\epsilon))$ is finite and fixed with respect to $n$; then if we let $n\to\infty$ on both sides we find that $\frac{1}{n}(a_N-N(a\pm\epsilon))\to0$:

$$a-\epsilon\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}\le a+\epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ is here arbitrary, I may take limits as $\epsilon\to0^+$, and the squeeze theorem yields that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=a$$

You had exactly the right idea!

Comment: Before to write :
$$\lim \dfrac{a_n}{n}$$
we have to be sure that $\left(\dfrac{a_n}{n}\right)$ converges.

Comment: From the line "The quantity ..." we have to write : 
$$\exists N' \geq N, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \left|\dfrac{a_N - N}{n} \right| \leq \varepsilon$$
Then :
$$\forall n \geq N', a - 2 \varepsilon \leq \dfrac{a_n}{n} \leq a + 2 \varepsilon$$
Now we can deduce that :
$$\dfrac{a_n}{n} \to a$$

Comment: Thank you for this...Immediately helpful. Can i ask how you go about this kind of things? I just don't know where to start with these kind of problems. Have you just done enough sequence problems so you generally see what type it is?

Comment: And the term $\frac{a_N}{n}+\frac{1}{n}(n-N)(a-\epsilon)=\frac{1}{n}(a_N-N)(a-\epsilon)+(a-\epsilon)$ right?

Comment: @JerryCohen To the first, you’re welcome, and I’ll just say that I’ve read lots of proofs. I’m actually the first to admit my problem solving ability isn’t as good as it should be, but in this particular case I’ve just seen a lot of similar proofs and you did do the hard work already! Coming up with the telescoping series is the key to the proof. As for the second, I actually made an error in my expansion! I will correct it now

Comment: @FShirke can i ask you where you saw so many examples? I mean at uni we were just given some basic definitions and we are supposed to do all these by ourselves...Seeing some examples would definitely help a lot !!

Comment: @JerryCohen Your university hopefully has appropriate textbooks. My perspective on this is a bit different as I am largely self-taught - my education has been erratic, and consists of whatever I can scrounge from the internet... So my answer would be that you should aggressively seek out online (or physical!) resources, learn how to read Wikipedia, and get friendly with this forum - and don't be disheartened if it takes hours to finish an exercise, since this is a regular occurrence for me. The thing to be wary of with internet-based teaching is that you don't get much of a taste for (cont.)

Comment: Mathematical rigour, so this forum is amazing in that you can write up a proof of your own, or write up someone else's proof, and you can ask questions about how rigorous the proof is and why certain steps had to be taken, and you'll have a community of experts to give advice. For lots of analysis examples you can take more informal treatments (but still good!) from YouTubers such as Dr Peyam, who has many playlists on linear algebra, real analysis, basic topology, and provides proofs that can be hard to find elsewhere. But do beware of YouTube, in the sense that it is often unrigorous!

Comment: + There are pdfs, lecture notes and papers littered everywhere online from university professors and researchers; don't be afraid to go to the second page of Google if needs be, as access to a paper can be very instructive with regards to technique (but papers are often hard to read, so this forum can help you with that). I do recommend reading the proof of Stolz-Cesaro on Wikipedia; however long it takes to digest, once it is digested it will be an instructive example and it is a very useful theorem!

Comment: Thank you for this!!! I guess there is no quick way after all!